# Block reordering in a specific cell of a TableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I want to block a cell to be reordered.

For example:

I have a tableview with 4 rows but don't want that the first cell can be reordered.

Is that possible?

I've tried to use:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    [cell setEditing:NO animated:NO];
}
```

But doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer!

You can use the method **targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath** from UITableViewDelegate.

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath{
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0) {
        return sourceIndexPath;
    }
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Your UITableViewDataSource should implement `-(BOOL)tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` and return NO for indexPath.row == 0

```
- (BOOL)tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return (indexPath.row != 0);
}
```

[UITableViewDataSource documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource)

Comment: That cell can't be reordered, but when you click at EDIT BUTTON to reorder other cells, it changes the position too... I want it static.

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5 CODE:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {

    if proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0 {
        return sourceIndexPath
    }
    
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath
}
```